# Populating Tabs In An Existing Draft Envelope With The tabLabel

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to map data to tabs in an existing envelope using `tabLabels`? If not, do I just need to specify the `tabId` to indicate which tab should be populated with my data or is there a different identifier that I should use?

Background - I've been populating tabs while creating envelopes with a template based on [this process](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/). So if I'm populating a text tab, my json looks like:

```
{
    "textTabs": [
        {
            "tabLabel": "text",
            "value": "Jabberwocky!"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm mapping the contents of form fields from another form building service to the tabs in my DocuSign form and since I can specify which tabs should be populated based on the `tabLabel`, I've mapped my form fields to `tabLabels`. This works fine when creating a draft envelope.

But I need to populate more tabs in my draft envelope with the contents of subsequent form submissions from separate forms. I'd like to use my existing map of form fields > tabLabels but when I try with [Envelopes Update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/update/) or [EnvelopeRecipientTabs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/) (I'm not sure which I need to use here), DocuSign adds new tabs to my envelope, rather than mapping my data to the existing tabs

As far as I can tell, unique `tabIds` are generated each time a new envelope is created. So it'd be much easier to use `tabLabels`, which are always the same for each envelope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did have to use `tabIds` when updating recipient text, checkbox and radio tabs in a draft envelope but that's it.

As I mentioned, when populating tabs while creating an envelope I can use the `tabLabel` + `value`. When updating tabs, I can use the `tabId` + `value`.

Rather than creating a new map based on tabIds, I was able to fetch the draft envelope's recipient tabs and match them with the keys in my existing map, based on the tab's `tabLabel`, which remained the same after the draft envelope was created.

## Examples

---

### Text or checkbox tabs

**During envelope creation:**

```
newTab = [
    'tabLabel': label,
    'value': tabValue
]
```

**Updating recipient tabs for a draft envelope:**

```
newTab = [
    'tabId': tabId,
    'value': tabValue
]
```

### Radio button tabs

**During envelope creation:**

```
radioButton = [
    'selected': true,
    'value': value
]
```

**Updating recipient tabs for a draft envelope:**

```
radioButton = [
    'selected': true,
    'tabId': tabId
]
```

Obviously radio button tabs need to be put in a group like

```
newTab = [
    'groupName': groupName,
    'radios': [radioButton]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [EnvelopeRecipientTabs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/) like you mentioned.
Which means you need to have the `recipientId` for the specific recipient that the tab is associated with (every tab is part of a specific recipient).

So you build a URL like this:

```
PUT restapi/v2.1/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/envelopes/{ENVELOPE_ID}/recipients/{RECIPIENT_ID}/tabs
```

Now in the body of the request you need to have the following fields:

```
documentId, recipientId, tabLabel, tabId, value
```

`tabId` is a unique GUID that you can find if you check your envelope (you can make a GET to the envelope and include tabs)

`tabLabel` must also match

Comment: Thanks for this but I was able to just switch from using `tabLabel` to `tabId` when updating recipient tabs for a draft envelope. Would be nice if DocuSign's documentation just mentioned which 'keys' you need to use here.

Comment: Sounds good, as long as you got what you need...